# SwiftUI Link Long Text Alignment Multiline

Tags: swiftui, text-alignment, swiftui-link

## Problem

I'm using SwiftUI's [Link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/link) to open Safari from the application. But I have a long text for the link.

For now, the second line of the text always keeps aligned at the center.

#### What I want

I want to be able to use [leading TextAlignment](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textalignment) with it.

So I've tried to use [multilineTextAlignment](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/multilinetextalignment(_:)) but didn't work.

#### Code

```
Link("Some long text even very looong even that long text here!", destination: URL(string: "https://www.apple.com/")!)
.multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
```

Need help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Solution

My solution was using another signature of the Link itself with **multilineTextAlignment**.

```
Link(destination: URL(string: "https://www.apple.com/")!) {
    Text("Some long text even very looong even that long text here!")
    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
}
```

#### From Apple Documentation

```
public struct Link<Label> : View where Label : View {

/// Creates a control, consisting of a URL and a label, used to navigate
/// to the given URL.
///
/// - Parameters:
///     - destination: The URL for the link.
///     - label: A view that describes the destination of URL.
public init(destination: URL, @ViewBuilder label: () -> Label)
```

Hope will help someone else!

Best